# IB_DESIGNABLE Is not rendering in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

```
#import "UIViewTest.h"

@implementation UIViewTest

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/


- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if(self){
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    }
    
    return self;
    
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    
    if(self){
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    }
    
    return self;
}

@end
```

I have this code which works on the device, but doesn't seem to work in IB,

```
IB_DESIGNABLE @interface  UIViewTest : UIView
@end
```

I tried setting target to be inherited, tried specifying the module but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`:

```
- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
}
```

(If the repetition bothers you, refactor.)

Comment: So why does the same code works in swift without ` prepareForInterfaceBuilder`, I usually use interface builder for IBInspectable stuff, and how does IB create the view without its constructor ?

Comment: It's very difficult to debug IBDesignable because it runs out-of-process. You just have to experiment and roll the dice. I've long ago given up on the initializers; IBDesignable is supposed to call `initWithFrame:` (which is of itself a surprise) but I find it doesn't always do that. I don't know why and I don't care. My go-to methods, besides `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`, are things like `willMoveToSuperview:` which is shared between the canvas and the running app.

Comment: damn that sounds like really terrible thing. would be so much easier to prototype UI with custom classes if all worked well. for some reason above works fine with swift. I only use prepareForInterfaceBuilder to set IbInspectables, but now decided to give objective-c a try. anyway thanks for help Matt :) have a good day

Comment: Yeah, I don't recommend IBDesignable. IBInspectable is cool though.